# Missing legend when combining scale_fill_manual and scale_x_discrete in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following produces no legend using ggplot. I want a legend identifying the colors in the bars:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Response = factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)),
                  treatment = factor(c("Active",  "Placebo", "Active",
                  "Placebo", "Active","Placebo","Active","Placebo"),
                                       levels=c("Active","Placebo")),
              percent = c(16.81, 13.53, 17.42, 16.24, 25.33, 19.27,
                          100-16.81-17.42-25.33,100-13.53-16.24-19.25))

# Bar graph, with side-by-side bars
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Response, y=percent, fill=treatment, order=treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  ylab("Percent") + xlab("Outcome") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=factor(1:4), labels=c("CR","PR","SD","PD"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","red", name="Response", 
                breaks=1:2, labels=c("Active","Placebo"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got it all right except the last `scale_fill_manual` part. The part that gives problem is `breaks=1:2`. But this is not true, because you've set `fill=treatment` which means breaks are set to the `levels of treatment`. So, if you're to set `breaks`, it should be for example, `breaks=levels(factor(df1$treatment))` (which is redundant). You can change the labels, of course, to any value. For example:

What you could do to not get the legends removed is:

```
# No issues changing values of labels for every breaks set
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","red"), name = "Response",
      breaks = levels(factor(df1$treatment)), 
      labels = c("bla1", "bla2"))
```

However, this is sufficient if you want to use, for `labels`, the same values set to `breaks`:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","red"), name = "Response")
```

Here's the entire code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Response, y = percent, fill = treatment, 
            order = treatment))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) 
p <- p + ylab("Percent") + xlab("Outcome")
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks=factor(1:4), labels=c("CR","PR","SD","PD"))
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","red"), name = "Response", 
         labels = c("Active", "Placebo")) 
# although labels is redundant if you aren't changing its value
p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Response, y=percent, fill=treatment, order=treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  ylab("Percent") + xlab("Outcome") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=factor(1:4), labels=c("CR","PR","SD","PD")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","red"))
```

[image]